# how to extract features from the exist data based on time and date

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how can i extract total transaction count per user, monthly total transaction count, weekly total transaction count of the user, daily total transaction counts, hourly total transaction count and ten mins total transaction counts as well as the average of the six above periods using the following formula. the file is attached in [csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nW_sLFj2sSspV2fADo-7PKjK-xMiaZ8E) as shown below:

(total number of transactions)/((timestamp of earliest transaction - timestamp of latest transaction))

```
    user    date    value
29  2011-06-13 20:34:38 77609248
29  2011-06-12 14:22:36 184677003
29  2011-06-12 14:22:36 2397489
30  2013-11-19 08:35:43 2790480
30  2013-11-07 05:45:14 46873751
30  2013-11-07 05:45:14 100000000
37  2011-11-28 05:46:50 1000000
37  2011-11-03 08:17:27 1000000
37  2011-10-31 00:57:44 10000000
38  2013-11-26 03:49:44 1000031
38  2013-11-26 03:49:44 1000021
38  2013-11-26 03:49:44 1000012
39  2013-06-09 05:49:04 176875806
39  2013-03-22 18:25:34 8000
40  2013-11-08 13:53:44 1068051
40  2013-11-07 13:41:01 1014938
40  2013-09-06 17:23:35 1024979
```

I tried to write this code

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
d = {'user': ['size'], 'value': ['mean', 'sum', 'min', 'max'], 'date': ['min', 'max', 'count'], 'date': lambda x: x.max() - x.min()}
res = df.groupby('user').agg(d)

res.to_csv(r'out2.csv', sep='\t', )
```

But the output of the date is not as expected, i got this
output:

```
user    count   value_mean  total_value value_min   value_max   first_last_date
29  3   88227913.33333333   264683740   2397489 184677003   1 days 06:12:02.000000000
30  3   49888077.0  149664231   2790480 100000000   12 days 02:50:29.000000000
37  3   4000000.0   12000000    1000000 10000000    28 days 04:49:06.000000000
38  3   1000021.3333333334  3000064 1000012 1000031 0 days 00:00:00.000000000
39  2   88441903.0  176883806   8000    176875806   78 days 11:23:30.000000000
40  3   1035989.3333333334  3107968 1014938 1068051 62 days 20:30:09.000000000
```

‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Comment: Do you have any problems with other users editing your question? Everytime a user has edited your question, you have approved the changes and made further edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
asd = df.set_index('date').groupby('user').resample('1M')
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'mean':asd.mean()['value'], 'max':asd.max()['value'], 'sum':asd.sum()['value']})
df_result 

                         mean          max        sum
user date                                            
29   2011-06-30  8.822791e+07  184677003.0  264683740
30   2013-11-30  4.988808e+07  100000000.0  149664231
37   2011-10-31  1.000000e+07   10000000.0   10000000
     2011-11-30  1.000000e+06    1000000.0    2000000
38   2013-11-30  1.000021e+06    1000031.0    3000064
39   2013-03-31  8.000000e+03       8000.0       8000
     2013-04-30           NaN          NaN          0
     2013-05-31           NaN          NaN          0
     2013-06-30  1.768758e+08  176875806.0  176875806
40   2013-09-30  1.024979e+06    1024979.0    1024979
     2013-10-31           NaN          NaN          0
     2013-11-30  1.041494e+06    1068051.0    2082989
```

Sadly you cant use aggregate using groupby-resample to get the results of different functions.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but how can i use monthly total transaction count, weekly total transaction count of the user, daily total transaction counts, hourly total transaction count and ten mins total transaction using the same procedure. For example how can i find the mean, min ,max, sum per month, hour,week,day, and ten mins

Comment: @Alkaser change the resample argument to `1W` for 1 week, `1D` for one day and so on. if you want the totals without taking users into account you can cut the `groupby`

Comment: it works but i want to aggregate the users into one line. For example, if one user is duplicated 100 time , i want to aggregate all transaction belongs to a single user in 1 line and based on date 1m, 1w,1d,1h. and get the sum,max , mean based on the time series. Is it possible to do that? Thank you

Comment: take the result and groupby by user again and use your desired aggregation functions

Comment: Thank you. It works
what if I want to print the first row of each group, for example, I want to print the first row of user '29,30,40' and so on

Comment: I solved it by add first() df5 = df_result.groupby(['user']).first()
I appreciate your help